# Ошибка 500 при использование другого контроллера

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Здравствуйте. Установил проект Laravel, настроил роуты, все нормально работало (использовал один контроллер) далее создают еще один контроллер в нем также, как и в предыдущих случая, подключаю вьюшку, но при попытке перейти `site.loc/new` грузится пустая страница, а в консоли отображается ошибка: 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` 
Вьюшка присутствует.
Route:
`Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');`
Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AdminController extends Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    // $this->middleware('guest');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('admin.start');
}

}
```

Comment: Зачем вам (и нам) текст со страницы с 500? Смотрите что в логах. Если по каким-то причинам забыли включить детализацию ошибок, в том числе HTTP-исключений - включите.

Comment: Логи за сегодня путые.

Comment: Значит, меняйте детализацию логов, отслеживайте каждый чих, каждую строчку кода до возникновения 500. В любом случае информация о том, что у вас вылезает абсолютно стандартная ошибка сервера - бесполезна. Из неё можно понять только то, что даже своего обработчика 500 у вас в Laravel не установлено (а сделать это стоит). + попробуйте найти место падения в отладчике.

Comment: наверняка Controller не импортирован

Comment: Можно подробнее, как импортировать? Если не ошибаюсь, то до этого момента мне всегда достаточно было указания неймспейса.

Comment: `use Some\Namespace\Controller;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Трабл был в следующем. Права для каталогов я дал для текущего `user`, но apache стартовал, как потом выяснилось, под пользователем `www-data`, у этого пользователя не было прав на каталог с проектом, следовательно логи и экранирование ошибок было пустое. Решил проблему, просто добавил пользователю `www-data` возможность редактирование каталога с проектом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй обновить проект, набери в консоли:`php composer.phar update`, если не поможет, еще попробуй: `php composer.phar dump-autoload`